# Set state on changed dependencies without additional render (having a loader without additional renders)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

I have a huge component which renders long enough to be noticeable by user if it happens too often.
Its contents are loaded asynchronously (from a server) every time when a function "getData" changes, showing a loader during the wait.

I'm trying to write a code which will render the component only 2 times when the function changes - first time to show the loaded and the second time to display the data.
Using a standard `useEffect` causes it to be rendered 3 times, first of which doesn't change anything visible for the user.

```
type tData = /*some type*/
const Component = (props: {getData: () => Promise<tData[]>}) => {
    const {getData} = props;
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState<tData[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoader(true);
        setData([]);
        getData().then((newData) => {
            setData(newData);
            setLoader(false);
        });
    }, [getData, setLoader, setData]);
    // ... the rest of the component (that doesn't use the function getData)
};
```

The three renders are:

1. `getData` has changed - the effect runs and changes the states but there is 0 changes visible to the user (this is the render I want to get rid of)
2. `loader` has changed to `true` and `data` has changed to `[]` - a useful render that actually changes the UI
3. `loader` has changed to `false` and `data` has changed to a new value - a useful render that actually changes the UI

**How could I modify this code to not have a barren render when `getData` changes?**

Answer (score -1):

this is a very common use case.
what you can do here is a if() in the useEffect().
using a .then() complicates things. use async await to make it asynchronus.

```
   useEffect(() => {
    async function loadData() {
    const res = getData()
    return res 
    }
    let data = await loadData()
    //check if it's undefined 
    if (data && data!=='init') {
       setStateData(data)
       }
    }, [])
```

this is how i'd implement something like this. however it seems like the data fetching for you is somewhat complicated then this, but essentially, never fetch data synchronously unless you absolutely have to, and check if it's undefined in useEffect before setting the state variable so that it's only set once.

Comment: I do fetch the data asynchronously - the promise is asynchronous. This is not the cause of my problem, though. My problem is caused by the fact that the `useEffect` changes the states after the first render and the component has to be rendered again to show that.

Comment: react useState is pretty smart in the sense that it doesn't run the useEffect hook even if the data changes, If the data is not "changed", ie, it's just reset to the value it was before. however, i see that you also have setData() as a dependency and you're calling it again in the useEffect. are you sure this is not what is causing the rerender?